# JOOMLA: Можно ли взять value всех инпутов формы без jform[]

Tags: joomla

Как известно чтобы на сайте Joomla взять value всех полей определённой формы они должны иметь неймы вида `name="jform[something]"` и тогда мы можем взять их с помощью кода:

```
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$formData = new JRegistry($jinput->get('jform', '', 'array'));
```

Но можно ли взять value всех полей если их неймы имеют обычный вид `name="something"` т.е. без `jform[]` и сама форма имеет свой нейм например `<form name="myForm">` ? Если да то как?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Уже нашёл ответ:

```
// берём все поля формы
$jinput = JFactory::getApplication()->input;
$formData = new JRegistry($jinput->post->getArray());

// и получаем результат как
{"someName1":"someValue1","someName2":"","someName3":"someValue3"}

// оставляем лишь заполненные поля и убираем value кнопки submit
$json = json_decode($formData);
$arrayOfFields = array();
foreach($json as $name => $value) {
    if(!empty($value) && $name !== 'submit') {
        $arrayOfFields[] = $name.': '.$value;
    }
}
echo implode(', ',$arrayOfFields); // получим someName1: someValue1, someName3: someValue3
```